# How do I transfer ViewModel data between POST requests in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, post, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel like so:

```
public class ProductEditModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }

    public ProductEditModel()
    {
        var categories = Database.GetCategories(); // made-up method
        Categories = new SelectList(categories, "Key", "Value");
    }
}
```

Then I have two controller methods that uses this model:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ProductEditModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductEditModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // convert the model to the actual entity
        var product = Mapper.Map(model, new Product());
        Database.Save(product);
        return View("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model); // this is where it fails
    }
}
```

The first time the user goes to the `Create` view, they are presented with a list of categories. However, if they fail validation, the View is sent back to them, except this time the `Categories` property is null. This is understandable because the `ModelBinder` does not persist `Categories` if it wasn't in the POST request. My question is, what's the best way of keeping `Categories` persisted? I can do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductEditModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // convert the model to the actual entity
        var product = Mapper.Map(model, new Product());
        Database.Save(product);
        return View("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        // manually populate Categories again if validation failed
        model.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "Key", "Value");
        return View(model); // this is where it fails
    }
}
```

But this is an ugly solution. How else can I persist it? I can't use a hidden field because it's a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically implement my lists (for drop downs) as a readonly property.  When the View gets the value the property is self contained on what it needs to return the values.

```
public SelectList Categories
{
    get
    {
        var categories = Database.GetCategories(); // made-up method
        return new SelectList(categories, "Key", "Value");
    }
}
```

If necessary you can grab the currently selected item (i.e. validation failed) from the property containing the id that was posted and bound to the instance of your class.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the repository to fetch whatever data is needed and don't think it's an ugly solution:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductEditModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // manually populate Categories again if validation failed
        model.Categories = Repository.GetCategories();
        return View(model);
    }

    // convert the model to the actual entity
    var product = Mapper.Map(model, new Product());
    Database.Save(product);

    // I would recommend you to redirect here
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

To further refactor this I would recommend you watching the excellent [*Putting Your Controllers on a Diet*](http://www.mefeedia.com/watch/32189967) video presentation by Jimmy Bogard.

Comment: The reason why I say it's ugly is because it violates the single responsibility principle: the ViewModel should know how to get the data it needs to send to the view. If you need to set it externally, then it's just a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a BaseModel class where I keep all those property list as class attributes.

Like in the following sample:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList
{
    get
    {
        return GetCountryList().Select(
            t => new SelectListItem { Text = t.Name, Value = Convert.ToString(t.CountryID) });
    }
}
```

`GetCountryList()` is a function that ask a Singleton for data. This would only happen once in the app lifecycle

Another way for doing this, and if those lists are pretty big, would be to have a static utility class with the lookup table that returns the SelectListItem.

If you need to access a list that change from time to time then simply dont use a Singleton class.

Comment: Oh whoops, I thought you said `BaseController`, not `BaseModel`.

Comment: In my case is not properly a re-population for two reasons. First the data is not even read anymore from the database after the first time but is handled in memory from the singleton class. Second I dont have to recall any method to set the data back on the model class because it just has it available through its base class. When the view rendering takes effect the data is then binded to the relative select element.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but what would you in the case where the list can change from time to time? In my example, Categories can be added or deleted.

Comment: Well...then you must not use a Singleton class. I have edited my answer to add another consideration to do if those lists become a large number and you dont want to blow every model class with all that data.