# Maintain Checked Radio Group after Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post, radio-group

How can I maintain not only the questions and answers for a radio group, but the checked radio as well after a post that returns an error?

The Contact page returns a list of multiple choice questions. If there is an error, the view does not contain the answers or the selected values.

I have searched around, but not found an answer that quite puts it all together. This one is close: [How do I transfer ViewModel data between POST requests in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190866/how-do-i-transfer-viewmodel-data-between-post-requests-in-asp-net-mvc)

but I cannot believe there is not an easier solution four years later.

Ken says:

> you can grab the currently selected item (i.e. validation failed) from
>   the property containing the id that was posted and bound to the
>   instance of your class.

...which is what I want to do essentially: persist the checked radios. But I have to think that there is a way do this is without binding classes or setting hidden values.

This is what I have so far:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel();
        vm.Questions = workflow.GetQuestions().ToList();
        vm.Answers = workflow.GetPossibleAnswers();
        return View(vm);//populated radio group
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendForm(FormCollection form)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["FullName"]))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("FullName", "Must enter a name,");

            SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel();
            vm.Questions = workflow.GetQuestions().ToList();
            vm.Answers = workflow.GetPossibleAnswers();
            List<SelectedAnswer> selectedAnswers = ParseSelectedAnswers(form);
            vm.PreviousAnswers = selectedAnswers;
            return View(vm);//returns without the previously selected radios
        }
    //more code…
    }

public class SomeViewModel : RegisterExternalLoginModel
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
    public List<SelectedAnswer> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectedAnswer> PreviousAnswers 
    { 
        set 
        { 
            foreach(Question q in Questions)
            {
                q.SelectedAnswers = value.Where(t => t.questionId == q.objectId).ToList() ;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Parse Method

```
private  List<SelectedAnswer> ParseSelectedAnswers(FormCollection form)
        {
            List<SelectedAnswer> selectedAnswers = new List<SelectedAnswer>();
            var questionElements = form.AllKeys.Where(t => t.StartsWith("Questions["));
            var uniqueQuestionElements = questionElements.Select(t=> t.Substring(0, t.IndexOf(']') +1)).Distinct();
            var count = uniqueQuestionElements.Count();

            foreach(var element in uniqueQuestionElements)
            {
                long x = ParseElementToLong(form, element, "ObjectId");
                long y = ParseElementToLong(form, element, "SelectedAnswer");

                selectedAnswers.Add(new SelectedAnswer() { questionId = x, answerId = y });            
            }
            return selectedAnswers;
        }
```

So, the problem is that the view is coming back after the ModelError without any questions, answers, or checked radios.

I am using MVC 5 with Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not sending the ViewModel back, use the same view model you are sending to your view, and receiving from your view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendForm(FormCollection form)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["FullName"]))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("FullName", "Must enter a name,");
        return View(form);
    }
//more code…
}
```

If I'm entirely honest with you, I hate what I see here all together...

- What is FormCollection exactly?
- Why are you not creating a view model specifically for your form?
- Why are you validating the form values in your Controller Action?

  You can use annotations such as `[Required]` which would do the validation you're already manually doing.

Comment: That throws an error that says that it is expecting a view model, but instead received a form. FormCollection is a dump of the form (a string of strings). The form is very complex, and is updated often, so it is more convenient to just take the form and pass it off to the various workflows (which all have a serialize method), rather than keep updating the viewmodel. Generally, I prefer the viewmodel post, but in this case, the form collection is a down and dirty solution that works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work, your question is a case in point, would it really be that much effort to change it? Your only other option is to reconstruct the view model and it's values and return it the way I've shown you.

Answer (score 0):

> This will Work.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel();
    vm.Questions = workflow.GetQuestions().ToList();
    vm.Answers = workflow.GetPossibleAnswers();
    return View(vm);//populated radio group
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendForm(FormCollection form)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["FullName"]))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("FullName", "Must enter a name,");

        SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel();
        vm.Questions = workflow.GetQuestions().ToList();
        vm.Answers = workflow.GetPossibleAnswers();
        return View(vm);//populated radio group
    }
//more code…
}

public class SomeViewModel : RegisterExternalLoginModel
{
public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
public IList<Answer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
public List<SelectedAnswer> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
public IList<SelectedAnswer> PreviousAnswers 
{ 
    set 
    { 
        foreach(Question q in Questions)
        {
            q.SelectedAnswers = value.Where(t => t.questionId == q.objectId).ToList() ;
        }
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: That is half of it. The other half is maintaining the selected answers. I added a parse method, but it is still not working. See edit above.